# Setting session var

Tags: php, session

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['index_visited']) )
{

$_SESSION['page2_visited'] = 1;
$_SESSION['wrong_number'] = 1;

header('Location: index.php');

}
?>
```

I think that $_SESSION['page2_visited'] = 1 and $_SESSION['wrong_number'] = 1 never get set. Program redirect me on index.php and thats it.

What I have to do to set it?

Comment: unset $_SESSION['index_visited'] first?

Comment: Substitute the `header()` with some debug echos to figure out what is going on. What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` give? Do you use `$page2_visited` somewhere so that it causes trouble with `REGISTER_GLOBALS`?

Comment: What does the start of `index.php` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the session doesn't have time to properly save itself before the redirect happens.

Use [session_write_close();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to force the saving of the session right before the header redirect.

So it would be:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['index_visited']) ) {
  $_SESSION['page2_visited'] = 1;
  $_SESSION['wrong_number'] = 1;

  session_write_close();

  header('Location: index.php');

}
?>
```

[session_commit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-commit.php) works too.  It's just as alias of session_write_close()

Answer (score 1):

i bet $_SESSION['index_visited'] is set. perhaps you want

if(isset($_SESSION['index_visited']) and $_SESSION['index_visited'] == 1) {

remember, if $_SESSION['index_visited'] has been set to 0, that counts as set.

Answer (score 1):

The `header('Location: index.php');` overwrites the session setting headers.

The optional replace parameter indicates whether the header should replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of the same type. By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE as the second argument you can force multiple headers of the same type.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

So please try: `header('Location: index.php', false);`

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. This is not place for $_SESSION['wrong_number'], now it is working. Thank you for answers anyway.